# QGIS Modeler using File/Folder input paramerter

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, save, path

I would like to use the File/Folder input parameter to set a path for all output layer files. I was trying to connect the File/Folder parameter to my output from a model and set a default folder path.
I was trying to call the path by using @output_Directory but the path is not used. How can I connect the File/Folder input parameter with the model output?
[image]